# Correct conditional logic for multiple flags

Tags: validation, powershell

I have a file that resembles the following

```
C:\path\AP1\com1\web.config
C:\path\AP2\com1\web.config
C:\path\AP1\com2\web.config
C:\path\AP2\com2\web.config
C:\path\AP1\com4new\web.config
C:\path\AP2\com4new\web.config
C:\path\AP1\thirdFolder\web.config
C:\path\AP2\thirdFolder\web.config
```

This file gets output on every server regardless of environment. I am creating a validation script to only include the relevant lines for each server.

An example of what the server data looks like is this

```
<server compName="serverName102">
    <ip>192.168.1.1</ip>
    <type>App</type>
    <env>test</env>
    <instances>Com2, Com3</instances>
    <AppPools>bo, fo</AppPools>
</server>
```

If a server's `AppPools` setting contains `fo`, then I need to include any lines that contain `AP1`. If `AppPools` contains `bo`, then I need `AP2`, and obviously if it contains both I need both lines.

If a server's `instances` contains `Com2`, then I need to include any lines that contain `com2` OR `com4new`. `Com3` will be the `thirdFolder` lines.

I currently have several if statements that look like the following

```
if ($serverInst -like "*com2*"){
    $refinedResults += $allResults | where-object {$_ -like "*com2*" -or $_ -like "*com4new*"}
}
```

The problem is that I am almost positive that how I am doing this is not nearly the best way, or how I should be doing this. Can anybody provide some insight to the best way to perform this validation?

Comment: Why are you adding them to another list.  Instead of doing that, can't you just perform the action you're trying to complete?

Comment: Because depending on what server the validation is being run against, a large amount of that data is irrelevant. So I'm creating a second file with only the relevant data

Comment: What does $allResults contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem I see with your approach is the fact that you might end up with duplicates in your `$refinedResults` collection.

To work around this, you can employ a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) of strings.
If you try to add a value to a HashSet and it already exists, the operation simply returns false and nothing happens to the Set.

Assuming that `$allResults` is an array of strings, you could do this:

```
$refinedResults = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]

if ($serverInst -like "*com2*")
{
    $refinedResults.UnionWith([String[]]($allResults |? {$_ -like "*com2*" -or $_ -like "*com4new*"}))
}
```

For readability (and performance if you plan on processing more than one entry at a time), you might want to define your rules and extract from the `$allResults` before you start matching:

```
[String[]]$resultsCom2 = $allResults |? {$_ -like "*com2*" -or $_ -like "*com4new*"}
[String[]]$resultsCom3 = $allResults |? {$_ -like "*thirdfolder*"}

$refinedResults = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]

if ($serverInst -like "*com2*")
{
    $refinedResults.UnionWith($resultsCom2)
}

if ($serverInst -like "*com3*")
{
    $refinedResults.UnionWith($resultsCom3)
}
```

If the instantiation of $refinedResults fails, add:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
```

to your script before it